# django-admin.py startproject mysite не работает

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Всем привет!

Начал изучать django и столкнулся с такими проблемами:
При вводе
`python django-admin.py startproject admin_learning`
я получаю ответ

`python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Если я ввожу
`django-admin.py startproject admin_learning` , то получаю

```
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    cleanup
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    reset
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlreset
    sqlsequencereset
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
```

Подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
django-admin startproject site
```

вот так попробуйте